# Issue with rounded corner buttons in grid?

Tags: css

I have created the buttons in a grid format, Button and icons both are displaying as required but buttons are bot with come with rounded corner. How can I get the buttons with rounded corner for the below code.

```
   <fieldset  class="ui-grid-a">
         <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a href="#" id="SMS" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-sms ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='goToSms()'>Send SMS</a>
        </div>
         <div class="ui-block-b">
         <a href="#" id="EMAIL" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-mail ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='gomail()'>Send Email</a>
        </div>
    </fieldset >
```

CSS:

```
.ui-sms:after {
            background-image: url(icons/sms-b.png);
            background-size: 20px 20px;
            }
             .ui-mail:after {
            background-image: url(icons/mail-b.png);
            background-size: 15px 15px;
            }
```

Comment: Add border-radius property. Add css first in your question

Comment: where is your css ???

Comment: I have updated my question with css

Comment: Add border radius to ui-block-a .ui-sms

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: created the fiddle and answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
    <a href="#" id="SMS" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-sms ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='goToSms()'>Send SMS</a>
</div>

<div class="ui-block-b">
    <a href="#" id="EMAIL" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-icon-left ui-custom-icon ui-mail ui-nodisc-icon" onClick='gomail()'>Send Email</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-block-a{
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `border-radius` css property

```
    .ui-sms{
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

    }

    .ui-mail{
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

[**DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KpAm5/)